# Play video on Launchscreen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

How can we play video on the launch screen in flutter?
is that any way that we will do directly from flutter or we have to do it in the native platform separately?

As have done it with video_player package and it works fine
but initially, it shows the white screen in ios

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it on flutter itself

you just have to save the video file in to assets and used any video player plugin
to your first screen and then after put listener to that player and listen the event
when the video finished after you can navigate to next screen

here is the plugin that can help you to play videos [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

Comment: I did the same way back but it will show a white screen initially (as especially in ios. because in ios launch screen necessary ).